# LocalizedStrings not recognized in VS2015 Universal Project

Tags: c#, string, windows-phone, universal, localized

I'm trying to convert a WP8 projet to Universal Apps. I'experiecing a strange error regarding LocalizedStrings.

I use Multilingual App Toolkit to manage translations. I've updated to the latest version (4.0) which says it supports Universal apps.

The thing is it gives me this error in App.xaml: *The name "LocalizedStrings" does not exist in the namespace "using:StayfilmUniversalApp".*

And it is complaining on the MainPage.xaml too but not in other pages...
In MainPage.xaml it says that *The type LocalizedStrings was not found.* underlined in color blue the whole DataTemplate block that has a component which uses LocalizedStrings, for eg.:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TIT_WhatsNew">
        <Grid Width="250" Height="52" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <Rectangle Fill="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="3" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="250" />
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding LocalizedResources.WHATSNEW, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="21.333" FontStretch="ExtraCondensed" FontFamily="/Assets/Fonts/Frontage-regular.otf#Frontage Regular" />
            <Rectangle Fill="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="3" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="250" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

here is my App.xaml:

```
<Application
x:Class="StayfilmUniversalApp.App"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:StayfilmUniversalApp"
RequestedTheme="Light">

<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <!--<local:LocalizedStrings x:Key="LocalizedStrings"/>-->
        <local:LocalizedStrings xmlns:local="using:StayfilmUniversalApp" x:Key="LocalizedStrings" />
        <Color x:Key="PhoneDisabledColor">#66FFFFFF</Color>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PhoneDisabledBrush" Color="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledColor}" />
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles\PhoneStyles.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <!-- Other resources if you have -->
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

and My LocalizedStrings.cs:

```
using StayfilmUniversalApp.Resources;

namespace StayfilmUniversalApp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Provides access to string resources.
    /// </summary>
    public class LocalizedStrings
    {
        private static AppResources _localizedResources = new AppResources();

        public AppResources LocalizedResources { get { return _localizedResources; } }
    }
}
```

Comment: The "local" namespace definition seems to be malformed, take a look at this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747086(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I tried with clr-namespace but it desn't work also. And i've read somewhere that 'clr-namespace' was replaced by 'using' in Universal Apps. And whats even stranger is that all other pages recognize LocalizedStrings

Comment: Ok I've cleaned the cache at ...\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Phone Tools\CoreCon\12.0 and now all pages don't recognize LocalizedStrings...

Comment: Then you should have changed something when you added the page at question, did you renamed some class, namespace or something else? Just a stupid question, have you tried "Clean solution" and "Rebuild all", yes?

Comment: yep I'm always cleaning and rebuilding. the thing is that the entire project was "converted" from silverlight to runtime using this tool http://www.mobilize.net/silverlight

Now I'm cleaning all errors.  The project hasn't had a successful build in WP10 yet. May be some VS error that can't see the file only in App.xaml and that one page.

Comment: I've opened the page on Blend and a few more information was displayed that could lead to the source of the problem.

in App.xaml this new error appeared:

Comment: which error? there's nothing after ":"

Comment: in App.xaml this new error appeared:

Error Undefined namespace. The 'using' URI refers to a namespace 'StayfilmUniversalApp' that could not be found.

This is shown in this line xmlns:local="using:StayfilmUniversalApp".

Sorry I was called when I was editing the message and it timed out to edit... lol

Comment: If I edit that line in App.xaml... intelisense  only suggests my 2 other projects in the same solution which are Portable dlls it doesn't suggest the main project which is StayfilmUniversalApp

Comment: Ok... this just got a little more bizarre... After I've saved in Blend and went back to VS, unloaded the project then reloaded it again... now it suggests the namespace in intellisense but still says that LocalizedStrings does not exist in namespace using:StayfilmUniversalApp .... I think that some line in the project config it messing this all up or it is a VS bug....   :(   I've checked both .cproj of my main app and the portable project and didn't find anything that seemed out of order...

Comment: I've found the source of the problem... It's somewhere within my Intro.xaml Page... I've recreated the entire project 2 or 3 times and noticed that only when I add Intro.xaml page the LocalizedStrings don't get recognized. If I exclude that page and leave other pages that still use LocalizedStrings the error goes away. I'll try to recreate that page from scratch then I'll post here my findings.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has nothing to do with LocalizedStrings.

I gave up trying to fix the page and decided to recreate it from scratch. Doing so, I found out there may be a VS bug behind and is showing different error. because when I added a DataTemplate (this one below) to a HubSection it gave me this error on the entire DataTemplate block:
Cannot add instance of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Setter' to a collection of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.SetterBaseCollection'.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="YOTWDataTemplate">
        <ScrollViewer HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" BorderThickness="0" Height="548">
                <StackPanel x:Name="stackYOTW" Margin="0,0,0,100" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="420">
                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Portable User Interface" Margin="12,0,0,0">
                        <Run Text="{Binding LocalizedResources.EveryWeek, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}"/>
                        <Run FontWeight="Bold" Text="YES!"/>
                        <LineBreak/>
                        <Run Text="{Binding LocalizedResources.ChoosenByStayfilm, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}"/>
                        <LineBreak/>
                        <Run Text="{Binding LocalizedResources.ForYouToWatch, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}"/>
                    </TextBlock>
                    <ListBox x:Name="listYOTW" ItemsSource="{Binding listYesMovie}" Foreground="White" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid Margin="12,20,0,0" Background="White" Width="420">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="64"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="64*"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="119*"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="50*"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Image Margin="12" Source="{Binding user.photo}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="40" Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Stretch="Fill"/>
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="NAME" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Segoe WP Semibold" Margin="0" Grid.Column="1" Foreground="#FFAF252B" Text="{Binding user.fullName}" FontSize="18.667"/>
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="TIME" HorizontalAlignment="Right" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Segoe WP Light" Margin="0,0,14,0" Grid.Column="1" Foreground="#FF787878" Text="{Binding prettyPublicated}" FontSize="17.333" TextAlignment="Right"/>
                                    <Image Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,0,0,59" Grid.RowSpan="2" Source="{Binding thumbnailUrl}" Stretch="UniformToFill" Grid.Row="1"/>
                                    <Grid x:Name="TituloFILM" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1" Background="#CCAF252B">
                                        <TextBlock x:Name="TITLE" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding title}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Segoe WP Light" FontSize="24" Margin="14,0,0,0"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                    <Grid x:Name="GridYES" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.RowSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="80" Grid.Row="2" Height="30" Margin="14">
                                        <Canvas x:Name="iconYES" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="20" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="46" Margin="0">
                                            <Canvas x:Name="Layer_1" Height="15.391" Canvas.Left="0.409" Canvas.Top="2.304" Width="45.182">
                                                <Path Data="F1M10.991,0L7.327,5.987 3.619,0 0,0 5.741,8.801 5.741,14.9 8.913,14.9 8.913,8.801 14.61,0z" Fill="#FF9AA7B2" Height="14.9" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0.223" Width="14.61"/>
                                                <Path Data="F1M0,14.901L0,0 10.544,0 10.544,2.793 3.172,2.793 3.172,5.943 10.388,5.943 10.388,8.734 3.172,8.734 3.172,12.109 10.544,12.109 10.544,14.901z" Fill="#FF9AA7B2" Height="14.901" Canvas.Left="15.552" Canvas.Top="0.223" Width="10.544"/>
                                                <Path Data="F1M0,13.024L1.72,10.611C2.77,11.706 4.4,12.622 6.457,12.622 8.199,12.622 9.046,11.817 9.046,10.968 9.046,8.332 0.469,10.142 0.469,4.534 0.469,2.055 2.613,0 6.121,0 8.489,0 10.455,0.715 11.929,2.077L10.164,4.4C8.958,3.283 7.349,2.77 5.83,2.77 4.468,2.77 3.708,3.373 3.708,4.267 3.708,6.635 12.263,5.048 12.263,10.611 12.263,13.336 10.32,15.391 6.299,15.391 3.44,15.391 1.384,14.431 0,13.024" Fill="#FF9AA7B2" Height="15.391" Canvas.Left="27.575" Canvas.Top="0" Width="12.263"/>
                                                <Path Data="F1M0.537,10.053L0.067,0 3.485,0 3.039,10.053z M0,13.337C0,12.354 0.805,11.528 1.787,11.528 2.77,11.528 3.598,12.354 3.598,13.337 3.598,14.297 2.77,15.124 1.787,15.124 0.805,15.124 0,14.297 0,13.337" Fill="#FF9AA7B2" Height="15.124" Canvas.Left="41.584" Canvas.Top="0.223" Width="3.598"/>
                                            </Canvas>
                                        </Canvas>

                                        <TextBlock x:Name="N_YES" HorizontalAlignment="Right" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Segoe WP Light" Margin="0,0,59,3" Foreground="#FF35424D" Text="{Binding likeCount}" FontSize="20" TextAlignment="Right"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                    <Grid x:Name="GridCOMENT" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="70" Grid.Row="2" Height="30" Margin="14">
                                        <Canvas x:Name="iconCOMENT" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="26" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="28" Margin="0,2,0,0">
                                            <Canvas x:Name="Layer_4" Height="22.194" Canvas.Left="2.697" Canvas.Top="1.903" Width="22.605">
                                                <Path Data="M23.106,0.5L0.5,0.5 0.5,16.001 6.216,16.001 3.852,22.694 13.176,16.001 23.106,16.001z" Height="24.028" Canvas.Left="-0.5" Stroke="#FF9BA8B3" Canvas.Top="-0.5" Width="23.605"/>
                                            </Canvas>
                                        </Canvas>

                                        <TextBlock x:Name="N_YES1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Segoe WP Light" Margin="0,-3,0,0" Foreground="#FF35424D" Text="{Binding commentCount}" FontSize="20" TextAlignment="Right"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                    <Grid x:Name="GridVIEW" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="70" Grid.Row="2" Height="30" Margin="14">

                                        <Canvas x:Name="iconVIEW" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="26" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="36">
                                            <Canvas x:Name="Layer_2" Height="18" Canvas.Left="2.113" Canvas.Top="4" Width="31.145">
                                                <Path Data="M31.723,9.5C28.609,4.125 22.809,0.5 16.151,0.5 9.492,0.5 3.692,4.125 0.578,9.5 3.692,14.875 9.492,18.5 16.151,18.5 22.809,18.5 28.609,14.875 31.723,9.5z" Height="19" Canvas.Left="-0.578" Stroke="#FF9BA8B3" Canvas.Top="-0.5" Width="32.301"/>
                                                <Path Data="F1M9.409,4.705C9.409,7.303 7.303,9.41 4.704,9.41 2.106,9.41 0,7.303 0,4.705 0,2.107 2.106,0 4.704,0 7.303,0 9.409,2.107 9.409,4.705" Fill="#FF9BA8B3" Height="9.41" Canvas.Left="10.868" Canvas.Top="4.295" Width="9.409"/>
                                            </Canvas>
                                        </Canvas>

                                        <TextBlock x:Name="N_YES2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Segoe WP Light" Margin="0,-3,0,0" Foreground="#FF35424D" Text="{Binding viewCount}" FontSize="20" TextAlignment="Right"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                    <Button Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="{x:Null}" Margin="0,50,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" Click="Button_Click" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}">
                                        <Canvas x:Name="PLAY" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="102" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="102">
                                            <Canvas x:Name="Layer_3" Height="96" Canvas.Left="2" Canvas.Top="2" Width="96" Margin="0" Background="{StaticResource TransparentBrush}">
                                                <Path Data="F1M0,0L29.333,16.936 0,33.871z" Fill="White" Height="33.871" Canvas.Left="38.26" Canvas.Top="30.998" Width="29.333" Stroke="#26000000"/>
                                                <Ellipse Height="98" Stroke="#26000000" StrokeThickness="5" Width="98" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                                <Ellipse Height="96" Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="3" Width="96" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Canvas.Left="1" Canvas.Top="1"/>
                                            </Canvas>
                                        </Canvas>
                                    </Button>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="txt_NoConnection" Foreground="White" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding LocalizedResources.NoConnection, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,48,0,0" FontFamily="Segoe WP Light" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </DataTemplate>
```

and I say it is a VS bug because I found this: [VS bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3045072/xaml-template-copying-errors-across-vs-and-blend)

Comment: I mooved the the ListBox ItemTemplate out of the YOTWDataTemplate and the error went away... Windows Phone 8 Silverlight supported this. Universal Apps seems that took a step behind regarding this implementation